# z-index and CSS rotate

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have made some flip cards using CSS and HTML and CSS transitions

When you hover over the card it flips and enlarges. How can I position the current card that is hovered over to put it on the top using z-index with position relative as its having a problem using css `transform:rotate`?

So I need the card that is hovered over to be on top.

```css
/* The flip card container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.3);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
    z-index:1;
  
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
    z-index:999;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <h1>John Doe</h1> 
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
                            <p>We love that guy</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <h1>John Doe</h1> 
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
                            <p>We love that guy</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <h1>John Doe</h1> 
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
                            <p>We love that guy</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by adding z-index to `.flip-card:hover` class.

```css
/* The flip card container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px;
  /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}


/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */

.flip-card:hover {
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.3);
}


/* Position the front and back side */

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}


/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Style the back side */

.flip-card-back {
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
        <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
        <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
        <p>We love that guy</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
        <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
        <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
        <p>We love that guy</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
        <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
        <h1>John Doe</h1>
        <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
        <p>We love that guy</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` in your `.flip-card` class and add `z-index: 1` in hover case `.flip-card:hover`

The flip card container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
  position: relative
}
.flip-card:hover {
  z-index: 1
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.3);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
    z-index:1;
  
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
    z-index:999;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <h1>John Doe</h1> 
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
                            <p>We love that guy</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <h1>John Doe</h1> 
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
                            <p>We love that guy</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <h1>John Doe</h1> 
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
                            <p>We love that guy</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `z-index` on `flip-card:hover` also add `position:relative` to card

```css
/* The flip card container - set the width and height to whatever you want. We have added the border property to demonstrate that the flip itself goes out of the box on hover (remove perspective if you don't want the 3D effect */
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 180px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px; /* Remove this if you don't want the 3D effect */
}

/* This container is needed to position the front and back side */
.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

/* Do an horizontal flip when you move the mouse over the flip box container */
.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.3);
}

/* Position the front and back side */
.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

/* Style the front side (fallback if image is missing) */
.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
    z-index:1;
  
}

/* Style the back side */
.flip-card-back {
    z-index:999;
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flip-card:hover{
z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <h1>John Doe</h1> 
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
                            <p>We love that guy</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <h1>John Doe</h1> 
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
                            <p>We love that guy</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flip-card" style="float:left">
                <div class="flip-card-inner">
                    <div class="flip-card-front">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flip-card-back">
                        <div style="position:relative; z-index:1">
                            <h1>John Doe</h1> 
                            <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
                            <p>We love that guy</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```